# Attach sql query to a ListView control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my asp.net code:

```
public static void GetInvoices(int client_id)
{
    using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( GetConnectionString() ) )
    using ( var cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText =
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText =
        @"SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, o.Status, o.ShipDate, o.PostAmount, sum(p.PaymentAmt) as Paid
            FROM Orders o left outer join payment p on o.orderid = p.orderid WHERE o.DistID = @client_id
            Group by o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, o.Status, o.ShipDate, o.PostAmount
            Order By o.OrderDate Desc";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@client_id", client_id );
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();;
    }
}
```

How can I attach the information returned from this (which could possible be 0 rows returned) to a ListView control?

Is it as easy as

```
ListViewInvoices.DataSource = GetInvoices(1);
ListViewInvoices.DataBind();
```

Or is there a more involved to connect it to a sql query data set?

Comment: Did you try those last two lines?

Comment: I did not because it just didn't make sense in my mind.  Then I got pulled off on something else, will still have to come back to this just couldn't test those last two lines at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see GetInvoices is a void method; returns nothing. You will need to use DataAdapter to fill and return a DataTable or DataSet. Then the last two lines should work

Comment: Alright that makes sense.  I will add that and test it as soon as I can get to it.

Comment: OK. May be instead of last two lines probably you will need to iterate through the DataTable and construct ListViewItems and add to the list view.

Answer (score 0):

GetInvoices don't return neither DataSet nor DataTable, you're just executing the query but don't get the returned data in DataContainer aka DataSet or DataTable.